# Uploading an image to ImageBox in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, upload

I want to upload an image to `ImageBox` on an `Asp.net` webpage. I am using C# language
and for the browse I used `<asp:FileUpload>` tag. Any Ideas Please?

Regards

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="imgUpload" runat="server"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assess uploaded file through FileUpload and save it using `SaveAs` method. You can read more over [here](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/).

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(imgUpload.FileName);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
```

Comment: OK, but HOw can I display it in the image box?
I am doing this for Uploading a profile picture while registering for a website.

Comment: Set the ImageURL property with url of newly save image.

Comment: I tried this way (  imgProfile.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename; ) but it didn't work

Comment: You do not need MapPath, imgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/" + filename;

Comment: Thanks...but can you add this part (mgProfile.ImageUrl = "~/" + filename;)  to your answer Please.

Comment: Personal preference also is to use Path.Combine rather than manually building a string.

Answer (score 0):

try the links below i think these like can help.
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread32985.html#
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread112662.html#